# SQL Server login failed for user error 18456

Tags: sql-server

I installed docker and I run this command in windows

```
docker run -e "ACCEPT_EULA=Y" -e "MSSQL_SA_PASSWORD=MyComplexPassword!234" -e "MSSQL_PID=sa" --cap-add SYS_PTRACE -p 1404:1433 -d microsoft/mssql-server-linux
```

then I donwloaded SQL Server 2012 and in the server name I write localhost and in login : sa
password as you can see in the installation command.

but I get the error SQL Server login failed for user.

[image]

What is wrong?

Comment: yes it is my password.

Comment: so what is it?I just looked in a video it works like this way

Comment: the setup of the sql? before a year

Comment: yes, the same issue. but when I run docker run -e ACCEPT_EULA='Y' MSSQL_PID=’sa’ MSSQL_SA_PASSWORD='MyComplexPassword!234' MSSQL_TCP_PORT=1234 /opt/mssql/bin/mssql-conf setup. it shows me invalid reference format: repository name must be lowercase

Comment: how to get it correct? what to write before?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is your using localhost. Which not the interface where docker is listening

```
PS C:\> ipconfig

Windows IP Configuration


Ethernet adapter vEthernet (Temp Nic Name):

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::99d:bf5e:8700:56df%26
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 172.27.219.121
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.240.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 172.27.208.1
```

If you a `ipconfig` there would be a `vEthernet` interface. And a IP would be there. Use this IP to connect to the your DB server. Also make sure to provide the port # as `1404` while connecting

Comment: Thanks for your IP address I guess?

Comment: Nope, these are local IP addresses, so not my IP :-)

Answer (score 0):

With `-p 1404:1433` you mapped machine port "1404" to docker's default SQL Server port "1433". So your "Server Name" in SSMS should be `localhost,1404` instead of simply `localhost`